# add border in CGRect iOS

Tags: ios, cgrect

I want to add a border in a CGRect. Although previous solutions suggest either this:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle);
```

or something like this:

```
view.layer.borderWidth = 10;
view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
```

I cannot apply either of this in my approach.

In my mainView Controller I am having this code:

```
-(void)actionHint
{
    CGRect  viewRect = CGRectMake(kScreenWidth/2 -kMenuWidth, kScreenHeight/2-kMenuHeight - 70,kMenuWidth*10, kMenuHeight*4);
    HintMenu* hintMenu = [HintMenu viewWithRect:viewRect];
    [hintMenu.btnReveal addTarget:self action:@selector(actionReveal) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [hintMenu.btnNewAnag addTarget:self action:@selector(actionNewAnagram) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.gameView addSubview:hintMenu];
}
```

I am creating a game and I want a simple rect with some help actions to come on top of my current view. The code for viewRect is:

```
+(instancetype)viewWithRect:(CGRect)r
{
    HintMenu* hint = [[HintMenu alloc] initWithFrame:r];
    hint.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    UIImage* image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn"];
    ... rest of items in the cgrect
    return hint;
}
```

Where should I add the code for adding the borders and what that code should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `HintMenu` is a type of view so in its `initWithFrame` method you can do:

```
self.layer.borderWidth = 10;
self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to create a bordered rectangle. All you have to do is import the QuartzCore framework. Feel free to copy+paste this code.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    //give it a blue background
    self.layer.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    //set the boarder width
    self.layer.borderWidth=5;
    //set the boarder color
    self.layer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;    
}
```